# Time not updatating when using sysdate Oracle on Windows

Tags: oracle, time

Not sure what causes that problem, but when I run query

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MM') from dual;
```

I constantly get the same time 15:08. I even check a different Oracle DBMS on different machine (also Windows) and got the same result.

Comment: I love this question. "Wait for an hour, it'll change" :)

Answer (score 13):

HH24:MM is giving you the hours (HH) in 24-hour format, and the Month (August, 08).

You probably meant to type HH24:MI... ;)

Answer (score 5):

`MM` is the code for month. You want `MI` for minute.